# Override Warning Showed Up in VSCode But Compile Not Error

Tags: solidity, visual-studio-code, function-override

I have a smart contract like this

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControlEnumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Context.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/Pausable.sol";

contract SampleContract is Context, AccessControlEnumerable, Pausable {
    grantRole(
        bytes32 role, 
        address account
    )
        public
        virtual
        override
    {
        super.grantRole(role, account);
        // do stuff after grantRole
    }
}
```

Somehow, this raise error in VS Code

```
Function needs to specify overridden contracts "AccessControl" and "IAccessControl".
```

But, when I tried to compiled it using `solc 0.8.11`, nothing happened. The compiler run successfully. I want to get rid of the error by adding `override(AccessControl, IAccessControl)`, but the compiler raised error like this

```
TypeError: Invalid contract specified in override list: "AccessControl".
  --> project:/contracts/SampleContract.sol:15:9:
   |
15 |         override(AccessControl, IAccessControl)
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Note: This contract:
  --> @openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol:49:1:
   |
49 | abstract contract AccessControl is Context, IAccessControl, ERC165 {
   | ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

Compilation failed. See above.
```

I don't understand why is this happening? How to solve this? At least I want to ignore error from VS Code because it's kind of misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Solidity extension in VS Code is probably not using the same compiler version as your contract. Different compiler versions may have conflicting rules, so this will make sure VS Code uses the same compiler from your `node_modules` folder.

**Solution 1:** Change it in `File > Preferences > Settings`, search for *Solidity* and change the *Default Compiler* to `localNodeModule`:

[image: Default Compiler]

**Solution 2:** You could also change this in your project's local `settings.json`, once pushed into your repo, your colleagues can pull and they don't need to change this in their VS Code.

```
{
    "solidity.defaultCompiler": "localNodeModule",
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think first of all you need to add `function` keyword before `grandRole`, in Solidity every method implementation starts with function keyword so it will identify your property as method. In other hand you need to always ovveride method in all parent contracts, as Solidity has multi extend OOP it should be done in a following way.

```
contract SampleContract is Context, AccessControlEnumerable, Pausable {
    function grantRole(
        bytes32 role,
        address account
    )
        public
        virtual
        override(AccessControl, IAccessControl) // check this line
    {
        super.grantRole(role, account);
        // do stuff after grantRole
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you :)